# SSIS pckage run from file system

Tags: ssis

Initially I deployed packages on SQL server but since my machine is not having SSIS installed I faced issue of version while executing the packages. Then I deployed packages to file system on server which has SQL server enterprise edition with SSIS installed on it. I access the folder on server where I have deployed packages from my system and execute the package but I get error saying "cannot run on this edition of integration services, need higher version." Do I need to rmote login (RDP) to execute package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know whom to blame but my package is running successfully. The solution was restart the server!!! (though client was not ready to that for long period of time)